# Code to read & write in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to write code to read and write the XML but I am facing some errors, Could please someone provide the sample code to read XML in grid and can update/insert data from grid which will be saved in following sample xml file.

Sample XML file:

I am facing the below exception:
 The assembly with display name '...XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '.....XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: In general, [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) is considered to be an *easier* to use XML serialization class when compared with `XmlSerializer`. Also, WPF is not a 'code' in which you write serializers. Rather, it is an application architecture for UI's etc. Your desire for an XmlSerializer is a C# issue not a WPF one (unless you're trying XPath UI bindings).

Answer (score 1):

to load xml data onto a grid you should use DataSet. convert XML data into dataset and load it on to the grid view i think this should work

```
//Method for serialization. Just In case if you went wrong some where
    public static string SerializeElement(object transactiondetails)
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(transactions));
                StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
                XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
                ser.Serialize(writer1, transactiondetails);
                writer1.Close();
                return sww.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Should use `using` to dispose of `writer1` deterministically rather than explicitly calling `.Close()`.